# Prevent wrap to new line for objects

Tags: javascript, prettier, prettier-vscode

I tried everything in `settings.json` in VS-Code, but with no success.
I have an Array with objects inside and dont want it to being formatted to new line.

```js
var testdata = [{t: Date.now()-9000,y: 0},{t: Date.now()-8000,y: 0},{t: Date.now()-7000,y: 0},{t: Date.now()-6000,y: 0}];
```

shall stay as it is, but the keys are being moved to new lines:

```
var testdata = [{
        t: Date.now() - 9000,
        y: 0
    }, {
        t: Date.now() - 8000,
        y: 0
    }, {
        t: Date.now() - 7000,
        y: 0
    }, {
        t: Date.now() - 6000,
        y: 0
    }, {
        t: Date.now() - 5000,
        y: 0
    }
]
```

VS Code:
Prettier 5.9.1

tried with

- `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "preserve-aligned"`,
- `"editor.wordWrapColumn": 10000`,
- `"html.format.preserveNewLines": true`,
- `"prettier.printWidth": 2100`,

Comment: If you just want it for a single line you can use [`// prettier-ignore`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript)

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Mhh. But then i have to manually add prettier-ignore everywhere. 
Is there another option to prevent the line wrapping?

Comment: Not that I know of